# Play sound from library by its name in Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

Is it possible to play a sound from the library by its name and not Class Linkage in actionscript3?? Meaning if I have a sound named "mysound.mp3" in library and does not have a linkage name, can I play it dynamically in my code by any means?? I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it's not possible, because if you don't use your sound in some timeline it will not even be exported to swf.

If you are using it in timeline (so it's exported to swf) it's possible to extract it in run-time with some third-party libraries/as3 decompilers by parsing raw swf bytes, but I don't advice to go with that way - it's not stable and system resources consuming.

It's much more easy to set linkage, btw why you don't want to do that?

Comment: Because adding a linkage name to movieclips or sounds is not allowed for externally downloaded swfs in ios apps...

Comment: then you can create move clips and place sounds in timeline, and control sound playback by _MovieClip_ methods _play/stop/gotoAndPlay_, give a linkage name to these movie clips, so you can create them at runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an instance of a Class dynamically, you must call it by its AS Linkage. Why proceed in any other way?

**How to proceed?**

Right-click the sound file in your library and make it available for ActionScript by editing its Linkage properties: select Linkage to open up the linkage window > ActionScript > ActionScript Linkage : MySound (select Export for ActionScript and Export in frame 1). That will export your sound file as an ActionScript Class called MySound.

You can also select Linkage from the Library Panel menu and create or modify your AS Linkage:

[image]

So you can create a new instance of your sound Class and play it:

```
var s:MySound = new MySound();
s.play();
```

Comment: I know this, but I dont want to assign ASLinkage. I want to give a sound its ASLinkage dynamically through my code!